# Send request with custom Cookie jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, request

I need to send a GET request from localhost to another domain with some custom cookies.
The server has Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to *.
I was thinking of something like this:

```
$.get({ url : "domain-a.com/getreq" , cookies : {"cookie_name1" : "value1" , "cookie_name2" : "value2" }});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: Cookies are added to requests by the browser itself. You can't control that. Use `withCredentials` if need to include cookies from other domain

Comment: Dinesh that was just a concept not real code.